# Python - writing string to HTML file causes computational issues

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, notepad++, file-writing

I appreciate that this may be an issue with my computer/software, but I want to double check that my code isn't causing the problem before ruling it out.

I have written a fairly simple program. I have a short list of strings read in from a text file, then with a different text file open, I iterate over each word in the second text file, checking if the first two letters of the word are contained in the first list of strings.
Then, if that condition is fulfilled, I use string interpolation to insert that word into a string of HTML code. Finally, I append that string to an existing empty .html. When finished iterating through, I close the html file.

```
with open("strings.txt", "r") as f:
    strings = f.read().splitlines()
    
urlfile = open("links.html", "a")

with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read().splitlines()
    
    for word in text:
        if word[:2] in strings:
            html = '<a href="[URL]/{}">'.format(word)
            urlfile.write(html)

urlfile.close()
```

so far there doesn't actually seem to be any issues with my code doing what I want - I am generating the right html code and if I print it to console it does so quickly. It is being appended to the html file.
The problem I have is that something I am doing must be computationally expensive or problematic, because Notepad++ freezes every time I try to check links.html for the results. I have managed to see that it looks correct, but Notepad++ then becomes unusable, and my computer is clearly straining. The only solution I have is to close anything related to the html file.

None of the lists used are long and all the operations should in theory be quite simple, so I feel as though I must be doing something wrong. Am I writing to files in an unsafe way? Am I doing something wildly expensive that I'm just missing? I am using Notepad++ v7.9.5, Python 3, and Anaconda prompt.

EDIT: I am now able to access the html file on my browser and on Notepad++ without issue. I think the source of the problem was some laptop software updating in the background without me noticing. I'll check that first next time!

Comment: what would happen if you open this HTML file in browser? to open this file in browser, need to tweak the code little bit so that browser shows the links- `html = '<a href="[URL]/{}"> my_link </a> <br>'.format(word)` .

Comment: @simpleApp at the time of posting, the html file wouldnt open in my browser either. But everything seems to be fixed now - I can look at the html file on Notepad++ without issue. The links appear on the browser too, so all is well. You did remind me that I forgot to close the </a> tag though! Thanks!